# Route [invitations.store] not defined. (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel-jobs\resources\views\jobs\show.blade.php). How to fix?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to create a pop-up like in the following image:

[image]

But I'm getting an error in the line shown below.

This is my file show.blade.php:

```
<!-- this line produces the error -->
<a href="{!! route('invitations.store') !!}" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="event.preventDefault() >
    Apply now
</a>
```

Comment: Please edit the question and add your `routes/web.php` file

Comment: Is there any specific error message coming out? Or is it simply not showing what you expected?